# Silverlight Order form - use DataForm?

Tags: silverlight, dataform

I need to design an order form where one row represents and order line and the customer can add item to order. I then want to display a new row under then added row for the customer to add another item.

I'm thinking I should use a DataForm, but how do I display all rows at once rather than paging through the line items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn why do I always find the answer right after I've posted on StackOverflow!

So, I've kind of figured it out thanks to [this post](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/18714.aspx).

Basically, use a DataGrid to list the line items and just .Add a lineitem.